# Why is the method being run at the end?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I am trying to recover all the animal objects based on certain parameters. First I need to retrieve their location from parse as well as the name, but since I am importing more than one and using geocoder, I am using strings, and not an array. So instead of appending the imported information into an array, I am mutating a variable. What I though would happen is the query would go through the first object then run the retrieveLocation method, then proceed to the next object imported from parse, but instead it imports everything then runs the method, so in the end I only get 1 object instead of how many are supposed to be imported.

```
let query = PFQuery(className: "Animals")
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) in
        if(error == nil){
            for object in objects!{
                        if let addressobj = object["Add"] as? NSDictionary{
                            if let address = addressobj["address"] as? String{

                                self.addr = address
                                print("sdfadsf \(self.addr)")

                            }
                        }
                        if let name = object["Name"] as? String{
                            self.impname = name
                            print("rturrty \(self.impname)")
                            self.retrieveLocation()
                        }
                 }
           }
      }
func retrieveLocation(){
    let geocoder = CLGeocoder()

        geocoder.geocodeAddressString(addr, completionHandler: {(placemarks, error) -> Void in
            if((error) != nil){
                print("Error", error)
            }
            if let placemark = placemarks?.first {
                let coordinates = PFGeoPoint(location: placemark.location)
                if(whatever is true){
                 append the name and address into an array. This is the part where I just get repeats of the LATEST  imported object.
              }
            }

        })

}
```

Comment: is `retrieveLocation( )` asynchronous or synchronous? My guess is that it is asynchronous, which means that the function reaches the for-loop, continues through conditional binding, and upon calling `retrieveLocation( )` the method immediately returns to the caller, which then iterates back thru the for loop again, before `retrieveLocation( )` actually retrieves the desired location. perhaps make `retrieveLocation( )` synchronous, or simply append all your addresses your array and iterate through the array, which is probably the best option.

Comment: Yes it is asynchronous how would I make it synchronous?

Comment: You can read into grand central dispatch to start. You can dispatch to a synchronous queue, by calling `dispatch_sync(...)` on one of the predefined global queues.No guarantee that this solves your issue though. Why do you not want to append the addresses to an array?

Comment: If I did append an address to the array, I would end up with say 10, would I for loop through the geocoder to get the coordniates of each one?

Comment: Ya, i would configure `retrieveLocation( )` to take a parameter which will be the address you wish to retrieve, then use a for loop to iterate thru the array of addresses, each time passing a new location to `retrieveLocation( )`

Comment: Ok I will try that out, but for the dispatch_sync what do I do after this? http://puu.sh/oqW2B/154eb5e540.png

Comment: With your current code, does it print 10 different address? or does it print the same address 10 times? or does it print just one address?

Comment: 10 times the same address

Comment: `dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_UTILITY, 0)){...}` inside the closure you will put the method that you wish to call synchronously. But keep in mind that if you call an asynchronous method on a synchronous queue, it is just gong to return to the caller near immediately anyway.

Comment: Really? the calls to print inside the for-loop are printing the same address each time? Because if thats the case then it would seem that you are retrieving the same object from parse each time. I thought you meant that AFTER the for-loop calls `retrieveLocation( )` for each value, then it was `retrieveLocation( )` that was giving the same address 10 times. But you are saying that inside the for loop the same address is printed 10 times?

Comment: No inside the loop I get 10 different values, but inside the retrieveLocation function I get all the same values,and that value is the latest retrieved value in the parse retrieval.

Comment: Ok good that makes more sense.Then what i was saying should work. If you just append each value to an array and then iterate thru the array, each time passing a new location string to `retrieveLocation( )`, it should give you 10 unique locations.

Comment: Actually, all you should need to do is replace `self.addr` with a local variable, and then pass that to `retrieveLocation ( )`. the problem with using the instance variable is that it gets overwritten each time the loop goes thru, and by the time `geocodeAddressString( )` is called, the variable only holds one location string which is the last one that was in the for loop

Comment: So I would have a variable in the parse retrieval function, and pass that as a parameter in the retrieveLocation funrciton?

Comment: Correct, i just posted an answer as an example

Answer (score 0):

This should work if you use a local variable and pass this local variable to an implementation of retrieveLocation that takes a string as a parameter `retrieveLocation(address: String)`

```
let query = PFQuery(className: "Animals")
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) in
    if(error == nil){
      for object in objects!{
      if let addressobj = object["Add"] as? NSDictionary{
        if let address = addressobj["address"] as? String{

        let newAddress = address
        print("sdfadsf \(self.addr)")

        }
      }
   if let name = object["Name"] as? String{
     self.impname = name
     print("rturrty \(self.impname)")
     self.retrieveLocation(newAdress)
    }
  }
 }
}

func retrieveLocation(address: String){
    let geocoder = CLGeocoder()

    geocoder.geocodeAddressString(address, completionHandler: {(placemarks, error) -> Void in
        if((error) != nil){
            print("Error", error)
        }
        if let placemark = placemarks?.first {
            let coordinates = PFGeoPoint(location: placemark.location)
            if(whatever is true){
                append the name and address into an array. This is the part where I just get repeats of the LATEST  imported object.
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Problem seems to be that by the time `self.addr` is being used in the geocodeAddresString method, the for-loop has finished and thus overwritten all the previous values that were at one point individually held by `self.addr`. By using a local variable, it will be sure to use a unique value to geocodeAddressString each time it is executed